# Error fetching remote repo 'origin' with returned status code 143 from Jenkins Job

Tags: git, jenkins, timeout, clone, checkout

I am using Jenkin version:2.138.2 and git version: 2.16.2. I used to run one of the Jenkins job which was working fine from long back. But now unfortunately without any configuration change in Jenkins slave machine, the checkout process stops with below message :

[Pipeline] git

using credential 
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository

```
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10

 > git config remote.origin.url <https://path-to-remote-repo>.git # 

timeout=10

Fetching upstream changes from <https://path-to-remote-repo>.git

 > git --version # timeout=10

using GIT_ASKPASS to set credentials <service-account-name> Account
 > git fetch --tags --progress <https://path-to-remote-repo>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*


**And after 10 minutes, fails with following exception:**

ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from <https://path-to-remote-repo>.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:894)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1161)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1192)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:120)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:90)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:77)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git fetch --tags --progress <https://path-to-remote-repo>.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 143:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Counting objects: 1   


remote: Counting objects: 152414           
remote: Counting objects: 960513, done.        
remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/184913)           
remote: Compressing objects:   1% (1850/184913)           
remote: Compressing objects:   2% (3699/184913)           
remote: Compressing objects:   3% (5548/184913)           
remote: Compressing objects:   4% (7397/184913)           
remote: Compressing objects:   5% (9246/184913) 

……………………………………………………………………………………………………………………………..

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:2042)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1761)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$400(CliGitAPIImpl.java:72)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:442)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:153)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$1.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:207)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:53)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:358)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine$1$1.run(Engine.java:98)
    ... 1 more
    Suppressed: hudson.remoting.Channel$CallSiteStackTrace: Remote call to JNLP4-connect connection from <slave-machine-ip-address>:63922
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.attachCallSiteStackTrace(Channel.java:1741)
        at hudson.remoting.UserResponse.retrieve(UserRequest.java:389)
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.call(Channel.java:955)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.execute(RemoteGitImpl.java:146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler.invoke(RemoteGitImpl.java:132)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.execute(Unknown Source)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:892)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:1161)
        at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1192)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep.checkout(SCMStep.java:120)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:90)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.scm.SCMStep$StepExecutionImpl.run(SCMStep.java:77)
        at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.lambda$start$0(SynchronousNonBlockingStepExecution.java:47)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        ... 1 more
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // dir
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
Finished: FAILURE
```

I tried with setting **Shallow clone, checkout and clone timeout options (Both with Jenkins file as well as from Job configuration page)**. Also checked lot of threads related to Jenkin timeout issue in web. But not finding any fruitful solution.

Trying to troubleshoot the issue from past one week. Any help would be highly appreciated.